# Can't connect to Remix after changing ganache-cli host?

Tags: remix, ganache-cli

[image]

[image]

you look at the bottom of the photo referenced, I've changed hosts.
I created a public server on AWS and ran ganache-cli on port 8545.
I can connect well with modules such as metamask or web3, etherjs,
but I can't access the remix.

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh... I found a way.
Browser remix only works on localhost, desktop remix connects to ganache on another server.